# Azure filtering the list_blobs read using blob name

Tags: azure, blob

We are trying to get the list of blobs under a parent folder name using python API,

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("*******")
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()

Instead of reading the entire blob list, we wanted to filter the specific parent folder and reading the blob list.

I think CloudBlobClient supports prefix filtering, looks like this is not available in python API.
Please correct me if this is not the case.

Is there a way to filter the blob list while reading from the server? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried list_blobs(name_starts_with="ParentFolderName/") ? See documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#list-blobs-name-starts-with-none--include-none----kwargs-

Comment: Try `list_blobs` it Returns a generator to list the blobs under the specified container.  It is for python.